# Unassigned php variable in WHERE clause of mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query with php variables in WHERE clause. But it does not return results if the variables are unassigned.

```
$customer = isset($_REQUEST['customer'])?$_REQUEST['customer']:'';
$territory = isset($_REQUEST['territory'])?$_REQUEST['territory']:'';
$status = isset($_REQUEST['status'])?$_REQUEST['status']:'';

$getOrder = "SELECT * FROM order WHERE Customer = '$customer' AND Territory = '$territory' AND Status = '$status'";
$getOrderQuery = mysql_query($getOrder);
while($iRow = mysql_fetch_array($getOrderQuery))
{ .... }
```

If the three variables are assigned, it returns results. What do I need to do so that the query will return results even the variables are empty?

Comment: Hmmm.  Before thinking about that problem, switch to mysqli or PDO and use a parameterized query.

Comment: just add a `OR Customer = ''` at the back of the statement?

Comment: If I use OR instead of AND the query will return incorrect results.

Comment: What I'm saying is to do something like this `"SELECT * FROM order WHERE (Customer = '$customer' OR Customer = '') AND (Territory = '$territory' OR Territory = '') AND (Status = '$status' OR Status = '')";`

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment on your post but I can leave an answer.

Try to `echo $getOrder;`
make sure the variables have what you expect and then take the query and execute it directly on the database using MySQL client or phpMyAdmin.

Also, you should escape your variables as you are valuable to a SQL injection attack. I like to use [PDO API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

you can also try this based on the comment below

```
SELECT * FROM order 
WHERE IFNULL(Customer, '') IN('$customer', '') AND IFNULL(Territory,'') IN('$territory','') AND IFNULL(Status, '') IN('$status','')";
```

Comment: I think want OP wants is to return the results even though if the variables are empty.